# lambda expression on input arguments

Tags: lambda, snakemake

Is there any systematic difference between *output* and *input* arguments in the eye of lambda expression and wildcards?

To give you more detail, the first two arguments of params (*ref* and *ref2*) have different output while the last two are identical.

Parameter *ref* returns me **empty** while the *ref2*, *out* and *out2* all give me what I expected.

```
rule HISAT:
  input:
    idx   = expand("{ref}.HISAT.idx.1.ht2",ref=REFERENCES)
  params:
    ref   = lambda wildcards, input:  input.idx[:-6],
    ref2  = lambda wildcards, input:  input[0][:-6],
    out   = lambda wildcards, output: output.file[:-4],
    out2  = lambda wildcards, output: output[0][:-4]
  output:
    file  = "{sp}/map/{sp}.SpliceSite"
```

Comment: What happens if you have only one element in `REFERENCES` and remove the `expand` in the input?

Comment: Does the `out2` line have a typo in it?  `out2  = lambda wildcards, output: **putput**[0][:-4]`

Comment: @bli, Do you mean "expand" is the reason for this difference!?

Comment: @khikho I don't know, just an intuition. This would be a test to prove or disprove this intuition.